# TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource in fetch during POST in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, firefox, httprequest, fetch

I am trying to send a POST request to my Spring Boot server from a React app on the same machine, using fetch. I allowed CrossOrigin from my RestController class. Both GET and POST requests work fine when I use Opera browser. Using Firefox, I can obtain the data via GET to React using fetch. But when I use fetch to POST, I cannot access the server and Firefox console says

```
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

Here is my GET request code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({messages: data, currentUser: data[0].sender, isLoading: false}));
```

and here is the POST code:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({text: this.state.newMessageText, sender: this.state.currentUser})
});
```

I tried it with removing mode, cache and headers areas, it does not work.
Here is my server class:

```
package com.ybalcanci.eternalchat.controller;

import com.ybalcanci.eternalchat.model.Message;
import com.ybalcanci.eternalchat.repository.MessageRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:5000"})
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    @PostMapping
    public Message newMessage(@RequestBody Message message) {
        System.out.println("New Post Request: " + message);
        return messageRepository.save(message);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Message> messages(){
        return messageRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```